# C# script to integrate Google map into Unity3D error

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine

I am trying to integrate Google map into my Unity3D project by utilising this below C# code in my Map game object which is 3D plain object:

```
using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class GoogleMap : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public enum MapType
        {
            RoadMap,
            Satellite,
            Terrain,
            Hybrid
        }
        public bool loadOnStart = true;
        public bool autoLocateCenter = true;
        public GoogleMapLocation centerLocation;
        public int zoom = 13;
        public MapType mapType;
        public int size = 512;
        public bool doubleResolution = false;
        public GoogleMapMarker[] markers;
        public GoogleMapPath[] paths;

        void Start() {
            if(loadOnStart) Refresh();
        }

        public void Refresh() {
            if(autoLocateCenter && (markers.Length == 0 && paths.Length == 0)) {
                Debug.LogError("Auto Center will only work if paths or markers are used.");
            }
            StartCoroutine(_Refresh());
        }

        IEnumerator _Refresh ()
        {
            var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";
            var qs = "";
            if (!autoLocateCenter) {
                if (centerLocation.address != "")
                qs += "center=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (centerLocation.address);
                else {
                    qs += "center=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", centerLocation.latitude, centerLocation.longitude));
                }

                qs += "&zoom=" + zoom.ToString ();
            }
            qs += "&size=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0}x{0}", size));
            qs += "&scale=" + (doubleResolution ? "2" : "1");
            qs += "&maptype=" + mapType.ToString ().ToLower ();
            var usingSensor = false;
    #if UNITY_IPHONE
            usingSensor = Input.location.isEnabledByUser && Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running;
    #endif
            qs += "&sensor=" + (usingSensor ? "true" : "false");

            foreach (var i in markers) {
                qs += "&markers=" + string.Format ("size:{0}|color:{1}|label:{2}", i.size.ToString ().ToLower (), i.color, i.label);
                foreach (var loc in i.locations) {
                    if (loc.address != "")
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (loc.address);
                    else
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", loc.latitude, loc.longitude));
                }
            }

            foreach (var i in paths) {
                qs += "&path=" + string.Format ("weight:{0}|color:{1}", i.weight, i.color);
                if(i.fill) qs += "|fillcolor:" + i.fillColor;
                foreach (var loc in i.locations) {
                    if (loc.address != "")
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (loc.address);
                    else
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", loc.latitude, loc.longitude));
                }
            }

            var req = new WWW (url + "?" + qs);
            yield return req;
            GetComponent().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
        }

    }

    public enum GoogleMapColor
    {
        black,
        brown,
        green,
        purple,
        yellow,
        blue,
        gray,
        orange,
        red,
        white
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class GoogleMapLocation
    {
        public string address;
        public float latitude;
        public float longitude;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class GoogleMapMarker
    {
        public enum GoogleMapMarkerSize
        {
            Tiny,
            Small,
            Mid
        }
        public GoogleMapMarkerSize size;
        public GoogleMapColor color;
        public string label;
        public GoogleMapLocation[] locations;

    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class GoogleMapPath
    {
        public int weight = 5;
        public GoogleMapColor color;
        public bool fill = false;
        public GoogleMapColor fillColor;
        public GoogleMapLocation[] locations;
    }
```

I found error on this line:

```
GetComponent().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
```

It shows:

```
Using the generic method `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent<T>()' requires `1'type argument(s)
```

As more details in following pictures:

[image]

In Unity3D, there are some errors as indicated in following pictures:

[image]

As you can see, in Inspector panel, under Google map script, it shows:

```
The associated script cannot be loaded. Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script.
```

And the bottom down, it shows:

```
Assets/GoogleMap.cs(79,17): error CS0411: The type arguments for method `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent<T>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

With my little experience on Unity3D, please help me out on how to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When accepting the answer correct, Please go for @Programmer 's answer. I owe him one :)

Comment: @UmairM lol we are just seconds apart so I don't care which answer he goes with. Assuming we are 5 minutes or apart then yes.

Comment: Time shouldn't determine the answer of a post. Quality

Comment: @FrankerZ Yes but both are the-same and should solve his problem. It's just that we both typed at the-same time.

Comment: ^ correction: you were 8 seconds early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there.

Replace

```
GetComponent().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
```

with

```
GetComponent<Material>().mainTexture = req.texture;
```

If you get run-time `null` error on this line of code, the use `MeshRenderer` since the image you uploaded shows that you are using Mesh Renderer.

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
```

Comment: Thanks and especially for the extra piece about MeshRenderer. It helps me out even more.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change that line to this:

```
GetComponent<Material>().mainTexture = req.texture;
```

This is correct syntax to use `GetComponent`

Comment: Thanks anyway, I just have to go for @Programmer's as his appeared to me just a fraction of seconds earlier

Comment: No problem mate. As long as you got the help, it doesn't really matter :)