# LocationManager C# script for Google map not working in Unity3D

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, locationmanager

Having integrated Google map into my Unity3D project (following the code in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978088/c-sharp-script-to-integrate-google-map-into-unity3d-error), or see the code for Google map script down below), I'm now running into a problem implementing LocationManager to get GPS data and update the Google map when GPS data is changed. Here below is the ***LocationManager script***:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LocationManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject map;
    public GameObject spawn;
    public float lat=0;
    public float lon=0;
    float lastlat=0,lastlon=0;
    public GameObject latText;
    public GameObject lonText;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Input.location.Start (); // enable the mobile device GPS
        if (Input.location.isEnabledByUser) { // if mobile device GPS is enabled
            lat = Input.location.lastData.latitude; //get GPS Data
            lon = Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            map.GetComponent<GoogleMap> ().centerLocation.latitude = lat;
            map.GetComponent<GoogleMap> ().centerLocation.longitude = lon;
        }

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //      <---------Mobile Device Code----------->
        if (Input.location.isEnabledByUser) {
            lat = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
            lon = Input.location.lastData.longitude;
            if (lastlat != lat || lastlon != lon) {
                map.GetComponent<GoogleMap> ().centerLocation.latitude = lat;
                map.GetComponent<GoogleMap> ().centerLocation.longitude = lon;
                latText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Lat" + lat.ToString ();
                lonText.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Lon" + lon.ToString ();
                //spawn.GetComponent<Spawn> ().updateMonstersPosition (lon, lat);
                //Add above after you complete spawn part
                map.GetComponent<GoogleMap> ().Refresh ();
            }
            lastlat = lat;
            lastlon = lon;
        }
        //      <---------Mobile Device Code----------->

    }

    public float getLon(){
        return lon;
    }
    public float getLat(){
        return lat;
    }

}
```

This code was compiled error-free. When I change lat and lon in Location Manager configuration under inspector, nothing change. I even test by loading it into my iPhone but location on the map is not changed but still stays the same as what is set in the Google map script. Here are all related info:

***Google map script***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GoogleMap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum MapType
    {
        RoadMap,
        Satellite,
        Terrain,
        Hybrid
    }
    public bool loadOnStart = true;
    public bool autoLocateCenter = true;
    public GoogleMapLocation centerLocation;
    public int zoom = 13;
    public MapType mapType;
    public int size = 512;
    public bool doubleResolution = false;
    public GoogleMapMarker[] markers;
    public GoogleMapPath[] paths;

    void Start() {
        if(loadOnStart) Refresh();
    }

    public void Refresh() {
        if(autoLocateCenter && (markers.Length == 0 && paths.Length == 0)) {
            Debug.LogError("Auto Center will only work if paths or markers are used.");
        }
        StartCoroutine(_Refresh());
    }

    IEnumerator _Refresh ()
    {
        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";
        var qs = "";
        if (!autoLocateCenter) {
            if (centerLocation.address != "")
                qs += "center=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (centerLocation.address);
            else {
                qs += "center=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", centerLocation.latitude, centerLocation.longitude));
            }

            qs += "&zoom=" + zoom.ToString ();
        }
        qs += "&size=" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0}x{0}", size));
        qs += "&scale=" + (doubleResolution ? "2" : "1");
        qs += "&maptype=" + mapType.ToString ().ToLower ();
        var usingSensor = false;
        #if UNITY_IPHONE
        usingSensor = Input.location.isEnabledByUser && Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Running;
        #endif
        qs += "&sensor=" + (usingSensor ? "true" : "false");

        foreach (var i in markers) {
            qs += "&markers=" + string.Format ("size:{0}|color:{1}|label:{2}", i.size.ToString ().ToLower (), i.color, i.label);
            foreach (var loc in i.locations) {
                if (loc.address != "")
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (loc.address);
                else
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", loc.latitude, loc.longitude));
            }
        }

        foreach (var i in paths) {
            qs += "&path=" + string.Format ("weight:{0}|color:{1}", i.weight, i.color);
            if(i.fill) qs += "|fillcolor:" + i.fillColor;
            foreach (var loc in i.locations) {
                if (loc.address != "")
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (loc.address);
                else
                    qs += "|" + WWW.UnEscapeURL (string.Format ("{0},{1}", loc.latitude, loc.longitude));
            }
        }

        var req = new WWW (url + "?" + qs);
        yield return req;
        //GetComponent().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
        //GetComponent<Material>().mainTexture = req.texture;
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = req.texture;
    }

}

public enum GoogleMapColor
{
    black,
    brown,
    green,
    purple,
    yellow,
    blue,
    gray,
    orange,
    red,
    white
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GoogleMapLocation
{
    public string address;
    public float latitude;
    public float longitude;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GoogleMapMarker
{
    public enum GoogleMapMarkerSize
    {
        Tiny,
        Small,
        Mid
    }
    public GoogleMapMarkerSize size;
    public GoogleMapColor color;
    public string label;
    public GoogleMapLocation[] locations;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class GoogleMapPath
{
    public int weight = 5;
    public GoogleMapColor color;
    public bool fill = false;
    public GoogleMapColor fillColor;
    public GoogleMapLocation[] locations;
}
```

Below two pictures show how I configure Map and LocationManager GameObjects respectively:

***Map***

[image]

***Location Manager***

[image]

So to sum this up, what did I miss in either Location Manager script or its configuration, or both? Please help me out and I'm very new to Unity3D development, so please bear with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know if the problem is your `GoogleMap` script or the `LocationManager` script. Does your `GoogleMap` script work if you pass it some random longitude and latitude?

Comment: @Programmer - Google map script works on its own as location follows lat/lon I set in Inspector/Google Map (Script). I think the problem more likely lies in Location manager script (I say "more likely" because I'm not sure if there should be something to add/change in Google map script to incorporate with Location manager script). If I pass random numbers of lat/lon in Inspector/Location Manager (Script), nothing change, location still follows what set in Inspector/Google Map (Script).